# ¿Como puedo finalizar un metodo en android studio?

Tags: java

Ejemplo tengo un:

```
Public void cargar(){

}
```

Y quiero finalizarlo con un boton para iniciar otro como este:

```
Public void info(){

}
```

Comment: ¿ a que te refieres con finalizar? por favor especifica tu pregunta. Revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta para que obtengas la ayuda deseada, saludos.

Comment: Que deje funcionar

Comment: Explica lo que quieres hacer. Es muy raro que empieces algo para luego finalizarlo bruscamente, ten cuidado porque eso puede provocar un crash en la App. Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué no esperas a que `cargar()`  termine, por qué quieres truncarlo?

Comment: Esque el cargar() trae informacion para llenar un recyclerview, pero trae toda la informacion, en el caso de info() trae filtrada la informacion y si tengo los 2 tendria la informacion duplicada

Comment: Yo pensaría entonces en otra forma de solucionar el problema por lo que has comentado en el ultimo comentario. Efectivamente, lo que quieres hacer te dará problemas, dale otra vuelta.

Comment: Vale gracias, estoy recien comenzando con todo esto entonces la verdad voy entendiendo de a poco

Comment: Pues empieza con el manual de java por la página 1, porque te va a venir mejor que empezar a escribir código sin saber ni lo más básico.